# Flutter making singleton class and getting Non-nullable instance field error

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is a simple class which i want to wrap `dio` class is singleton, as i enabled `analyzer` i get this error:

> Non-nullable instance field '_instance' must be initialized.
> (Documentation)  Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field
> initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.

my code:

```dart
const baseApiUrl = 'http://localhost';

class BaseDio {
  BaseDio._();

  static BaseDio _instance;

  static BaseDio getInstance() {
    return _instance;
  }

  final cacheManager = DioCacheManager(CacheConfig(baseUrl: baseApiUrl));
  final BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
    connectTimeout: 20000,
    receiveTimeout: 30000,
  );

  Dio getDio() {
    final dio = Dio(options)
      ..interceptors.addAll(
        [

          PrettyDioLogger(
            requestHeader: true,
            requestBody: true,
            responseBody: true,
            responseHeader: false,
            compact: false,
          ),

          cacheManager.interceptor as Interceptor,
          LogInterceptor(responseBody: false),
        ],
      );

    return dio;
  }
}
```

how can i resolve this problem for `analyzer` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a factory method to create a singleton in Dart:

```
class BaseDio {
  static final BaseDio _singleton = BaseDio._internal();
  final int value = 42;

  factory BaseDio() => _singleton;

  BaseDio._internal() {
    // private constructor that creates the singleton instance
  }
}

final baseDioSingleton = BaseDio();
print(baseDioSingleton.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i access to _singleton from outside of this class now? for example `BaseDio.getInstance().getDio()`

Comment: The factory method call `BaseDio()` returns the _singleton value. The last string in the example code illustrates that

Answer (score 0):

`Non-nullable instance field '_instance' must be initialized.`

Add a value to `_instance` or make it `nullable`:

BaseDio _instance = `someValue`;

or

static BaseDio`?` _instance;